# Can't get Icon image to show

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jlabel

I have been trying for a couple days now to get this image called star1.png to show up. I am trying to "shoot" it out from my stick man but I can't even get the image to show up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
    package my.testing1;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    /**
    *
    *  @author Jamie
    */
   public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame 
   {

   JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman.png"));
   JLabel cords = new JLabel();
   JLabel bg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\background.png"));
   JLabel star = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\star1.png"));

   int locx = 0; 
   int locy = 0;
 int i = 0;
 int x = label.getX();
 int y = label.getY();
 String cor= Integer.toString(x) +" "+ Integer.toString(y);
 boolean ph = true;
 boolean left = true;
 boolean Sph = true;

 public GUI()
     {   
     this.setSize(800,600);
     this.cords.setText(cor);
     label.setBounds(x,y,120,120);
     cords.setBounds(20,170,50,50);
     bg.setBounds(0,0,800,600);
     //star.setBounds(x,y,50,50);


     cor= Integer.toString(x) + " "+ Integer.toString(y);
     label.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()

         {

         @Override
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
          {
             if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
             {
                 //locx=label.getX();
                 //locy=label.getY();
                 ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\star1.png");
                 star.setIcon(newIcon);

                 star.setLocation(300,300);


             }
             if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
             {
              if (y>0 | y==0)
                 {
                     y=y+10;
                 }
               if (y>440)
                 {
                     y=y-10;
                 }
                 label.setLocation(x,y);
                 if(ph == false)
                 {
                    if(left == true)
                    {

                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman2Left.png");
                        //newIcon.getImage().flush();
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman2.png");
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);
                    }

                    ph = true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(left == true)
                    {

                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickmanLeft.png");
                        //newIcon.getImage().flush();
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman.png");
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);
                    }
                    ph = false;
                 }
                 repaint();
                 cords.setLocation(20,170);
                 cor= Integer.toString(x) + " "+Integer.toString(y);
                 cords.setText(cor);
             }
             if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
             {
                if (y>440 | y>0)
                 {
                     y=y-10;
                 }
                if (y<0)
                {
                    y=y+10;
                }
                 label.setLocation(x,y);
                 if(ph == false)
                 {
                     if(left == true)
                    {

                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman2Left.png");
                        //newIcon.getImage().flush();
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman2.png");
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);
                    }
                    ph = true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(left == true)
                    {

                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickmanLeft.png");
                        //newIcon.getImage().flush();
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman.png");
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);
                    }
                    ph = false;
                 }
                repaint();
                cords.setLocation(20,170);
                cor= Integer.toString(x) +" "+ Integer.toString(y);
                cords.setText(cor);
             }
             if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
             {
                 if (x<0)
                 {
                     x=x+10;
                 }
                 if (x>0)
                 {
                     x=x-10;
                 }
                 label.setLocation(x,y);
                 left=true;
                 if(ph == false)
                 {

                     if(left == true)
                    {

                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman2Left.png");
                        //newIcon.getImage().flush();
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman2.png");
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);
                    }
                    ph = true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(left == true)
                    {

                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickmanLeft.png");
                        //newIcon.getImage().flush();
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman.png");
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);
                    }
                    ph = false;
                 }
                 repaint();
                 cords.setLocation(20,170);
                 cor= Integer.toString(x) + " "+Integer.toString(y);
                 cords.setText(cor);
             }

             if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
             {
                 if (x<690)
                 {
                     x=x+10;
                 }
                 if (x>690)
                 {
                     x=x-10;
                 }
                 label.setLocation(x,y);
                 left=false;
                 if(ph == false)
                 {
                     if(left == true)
                    {

                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman2Left.png");
                        //newIcon.getImage().flush();
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman2.png");
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);
                    }
                    ph = true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(left == true)
                    {

                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickmanLeft.png");
                        //newIcon.getImage().flush();
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\stickman.png");
                        label.setIcon(newIcon);
                    }
                    ph = false;
                 }
                 repaint();
                 cords.setLocation(20,170);
                 cor= Integer.toString(x) + " "+Integer.toString(y);
                 cords.setText(cor);
             }
             //System.out.println(x+y);
         }
     });
     label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
         {
         //@Override
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
             {
             if(me.getClickCount() == 1)
                 {
                 boolean dd = label.isOptimizedDrawingEnabled();
                 boolean ff = label.requestFocusInWindow();
                 repaint();
             }
         }

     });

     JPanel p = new JPanel();

     p.setSize(700,700);
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation(GUI.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     p.add(cords);
     p.setLayout(null);
     p.add(label);
     p.add(bg);
     p.add(star);
     JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(p);
     getContentPane().add(js);
 }

/**
 * Creates new form GUI
 */
/*public GUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 102, 0));
    setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(10, 10, 700, 700));
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 700));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 604, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 376, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
    GUI frame = new GUI();        
    new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Didn't look at your problem but you may want to pre-load and cache all images before, because creating new `ImageIcon` each time a key is pressed is not a good thing for performances.

Comment: If you want that someone helps you, please explain what you expect (which image is displayed where and when). Personally I don't understand. (although, you may want to check at your image file names, it's maybe just a bad file name)

Comment: to preload would I do something like image ii=new ImageIcon("star1.png"); ? Right now I'm just trying to push 'S' and have the star1.png image to appear at (300,300). Once I do that I plan on having it move away from my stick man. I've double checked all file names they are correct and present.

Comment: Can you upload \ link the pictures?

Comment: is there a way to upload the pictures here? they are just some very generic ones I made in paint. Just a stick man and a star that he is suppose to shoot.

Comment: It's a matter of their size. In the question editor there is an image icon to insert images.

Comment: I had star.setBounds(x,y,50,50); cause both star1.png/star2.png are less that 50x50 and I thought that would set the size for it. Where is this question editor?

Comment: You just click to edit your question on the bottom of it.

Comment: I have to have 10 reputation to post images :(

Comment: I upvoted your question, should have a bit more reputation now. If not then upload them to http://postimage.org. I have trouble figuring out what exactly happens without knowing the sizes of the images.

Comment: It gave me +5 so here is the link to them from postimage.org: http://postimg.org/image/q6mypo7rp/   and http://postimg.org/image/g1prww0rb/

Comment: the other stickman pics are same size just showing him "walking" and "turning".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to kill yourself after this, but here is your problem

```
 p.add(label);
 p.add(bg);
 p.add(star);
```

You see? you place the stickman on top, then the background beneath, then star at the bottom, so no matter where it is, it is hidden behind the background image. Just replace with

```
 p.add(label);
 p.add(star);
 p.add(bg);
```

(or add star before label if you want it to appear above it when they share position.)

By the way, there are many things there you could write better not related to your problem. If you want I can post them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `KeyAdapter` is not triggered when a key is pressed.
Simply replace:

```
label.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
```

with:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
```

in `GUI()` constructor so that the Frame handles `KeyEvent`s instead of `JLabel`.

Comment: That solved the problem of me not having to click my stick man before I could control him, but the image still wont show up. Thanks for the fix though.

Comment: OK. You forgot to set bounds on `star` Label  (the line is here but commented: `star.setBounds(x,y,50,50);`)

Comment: It works for me (uncomment `star.setBounds(x,y,50,50);` and remove `label.` before `addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()`). With this, the star image is displayed (my own PNG)

Comment: weird. I wonder why I'm not seeing it? I just don't understand

Comment: Maybe your image is invalid or too big for this label size (visible portion of image in label maybe transparent with your PNG?)

Comment: Remove the image from the label and just put text instead. Can you see the label now?

Comment: If I change star.setIcon(Star1); to star.setText("DO YOU SEE ME?"); and I press 'S' I do not see anything

Comment: You also need to remove the image from the constructor of star or it could prevent you form seeing the text.

Comment: This is the constructor right? JLabel star = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\Java\\star1.png"));
If so, I removed the image and I am still unable to see the text.